# C# Func Parameter Overloads - Ambiguous

Tags: c#, parameters, func

I have two functions that take in different `Func` parameters. The compiler is telling me it can't differentiate between these functions.

1)

```
public static async Task<TResult> SomeMethodName<TSource, TResult>
(Func<TSource, Task<TResult[]>> FunctionToRun)
```

2)

```
public static async Task<TResult> SomeMethodName<TSource, TResult>
(Func<TSource, Task<TResult>> FunctionToRun)
```

The difference is slight - but it seems that the C# compiler is not picking it up and can't tell the difference.

Is there a reason why `Func<...>` type parameters' don't get checked?

---

### Edit - Adding User Method Call Code:

Error is on this line:

```
var data = await SomeMethodName<model, model2>(someModel, SomeOtherMethod);
```

SomeOtherMethod method:

```
public static Task<model2[]> SomeOtherMethod(model model)
{
    Task<model2[]> data = SomeThirdMethodThatReturnsTasks(model);
    return data;
}
```

Error Details:

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
SomeMethodName<model,model2>(model,System.Func<model,System.Threading.Tasks.Task<model2[]>>) 
and 
SomeMethodName<model,model2>(model,System.Func<model,System.Threading.Tasks.Task<model2>>)
```

Comment: Sorry these parameters are not optional. Edited.

Comment: Please show us the code that is calling the methods - this is an important part of your question. (I've downvoted until this is done, since the question is unanswerably vague - it all seems to work for me)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing preventing the type of `TResult` from being an array.

Let's take this example use of the method for a second:

```
var task = SomeMethodName((int i) => Task.FromResult(new[] { i }));
```

This code *compiles and runs correctly if only the second method is defined*.  In that case you're calling:

```
SomeMethodName<int, int[]>(Func<int, Task<int[]>> FunctionToRun)
```

The cod would also compile and run successfully if you only have the first method defined. then you have:

```
SomeMethodName<int, int>(Func<int, Task<int[]>> FunctionToRun)
```

Since generic arguments aren't a part of the signature, these two functions are identical for the purpose of overload resolution.  If both of the overloads exist then overload resolution identifies both of them as valid methods, and there is nothing that makes either one of them "better' than the other based on the defined "betterness" criteria.  Since it has no way of picking one, it results in a compiler error due to the ambiguity.

Comment: I hear this answer. It makes sense, but what's the workaround? Renaming the method? (Really not ideal if I have 10 of these methods).

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with inferring `TResult`, it's with `TSource`. When you have a lambda like:

```
SomeMethodName(x => x.Something);
```

C# has no idea what `x` is unless you tell it. Once you specify that, it should be unambiguous to the compiler:

```
SomeMethodName<string, int>(x => x.Something); // or
SomeMethodName<string, int[]>(x => x.Something);
```

Comment: You're assuming he's using a lambda.  What if he's providing a method group?  In that case type inference *can* be used.  You can also provide the type of the parameter for the lambda and then type inference will also succeed.  Clearly he's doing something like this as his error message isn't a failure to infer the type error.

Comment: @Servy yeah, I hadn't considered those cases; without seeing the calling code, we're all just guessing.